# Is it possible to hold the selected dropdown filters values while navigating to detailed page from list page and detailed to back to list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

On list page there are multiple dropdown for filter, after filtering list click to view details of list.

Is it possible to hold the selected dropdown filter values while navigating back to the list page from the detailed page?

[Click see the UX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqbJj.png)

Comment: Yes store the selected dropdown value in a state and check if the state has value, then set it that to dropdown and also while navigating back you have to be sure that your page will not refresh, some people use global loading which used to trigger on every url change and if that case you can store the selected value in url query param or in the cookie.

Answer (score -1):

You can store the value in state or local storage.

Comment: code sample, please?
I am new in development.

Comment: I can refer you a link for storing a value in state. You can use useState hook.
here is the source link.
[https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html]